# Differentiating between a JAR and an uber-JAR

Tags: java, jar, uberjar

I am currently developing a tool that attempts to infer whether a given JAR file is an uber-JAR or a normal JAR.

Among many other heuristics and checks that I am making to determine the "uberness" of a JAR, the one that is currently not very reliable is the one that checks whether in the root level of the JAR, other than the `META-INF` folder, there is only one folder that contains `.class` files.

For example, for the `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3` library, the root level structure looks the following way:

> META-INF/
>
> ch/
>
> org/

The `org/` folder containing `slf4j` components is probably needed for this specific version of `logback-classic`. Later versions, such as 1.4.0, only contain one root-level folder that has `.class` files inside.

Another similar situation occurs with the `junit:junit:4.13.1` library. This one has the following root-level folder structure:

> META-INF/
>
> junit/
>
> org/

In this case, the `org/` folder contains a sub-folder `junit/` as well, thus those classes are also part of the actual implementation of junit, only having a different package prefix. Although it is not an uber-JAR, my current methodology would flag it as one.

I am looking for a better heuristic that can effectively differentiate between normal JARs and uber-JARs. Any suggestions or improvements to my current approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course, if you invoke `java -jar queried.jar` *programmatically* then you're going to get errors from anything other than an executable jar with dependencies met. 'Uberness' is actually quite subjective otherwise.

Comment: By uber-JAR, in my case, I am primarily referring to JARs that contain not only the compiled Java classes, resources and metadata specific to a Java application or library but also all the dependencies required by the application or library.

Comment: I know that ... ;) Of course, strictly speaking, my 'solution' is not thorough as an execution path might *not* reveal a missing dependency, but it could be a start

Comment: @g00se, but indeed, your idea of *programmatically* running JARs and checking for errors may be one way of dynamically checking for "uberness". However, I was so far only limiting myself to static analysis.

Comment: That, I think, is not possible, at least practicably so

Answer (score 0):

One way is to look at each .class file (their [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-4.html) isn’t actually all that complicated), and check for String constants which appear to be class names that aren’t in the .jar file.

```
private static final Pattern CLASS_NAME = Pattern.compile(
    "\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*" +
    "(?:/\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*)+");

private static final byte CONSTANT_Utf8 = 1;
private static final byte CONSTANT_Integer = 3;
private static final byte CONSTANT_Float = 4;
private static final byte CONSTANT_Long = 5;
private static final byte CONSTANT_Double = 6;
private static final byte CONSTANT_Class = 7;
private static final byte CONSTANT_String = 8;
private static final byte CONSTANT_Fieldref = 9;
private static final byte CONSTANT_Methodref = 10;
private static final byte CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref = 11;
private static final byte CONSTANT_NameAndType = 12;
private static final byte CONSTANT_MethodHandle = 15;
private static final byte CONSTANT_MethodType = 16;
private static final byte CONSTANT_Dynamic = 17;
private static final byte CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic = 18;
private static final byte CONSTANT_Module = 19;
private static final byte CONSTANT_Package = 20;

private static boolean lastComponentIsUpperCase(String s) {
    int lastSlash = s.lastIndexOf('/');
    return lastSlash >= 0 && lastSlash < s.length() - 1 &&
        Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(lastSlash + 1));
}

public Optional<String> findExternalClassReferenceIn(File file)
throws IOException {
    try (JarFile jar =
        new JarFile(file, false, JarFile.OPEN_READ, Runtime.version())) {

        Set<String> classes = new HashSet<>();

        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries;

        entries = jar.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            String name = entry.getRealName();
            if (name.endsWith(".class")) {
                classes.add(name.substring(0, name.length() - 6));
            }
        }

        Matcher classNameMatcher = CLASS_NAME.matcher("");

        entries = jar.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            String name = entry.getRealName();
            if (!name.endsWith(".class")) {
                continue;
            }

            try (DataInputStream classFile = new DataInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(
                    jar.getInputStream(entry)))) {

                int magic = classFile.readInt();
                short minorVersion = classFile.readShort();
                short majorVersion = classFile.readShort();
                int constantPoolSize = classFile.readShort() - 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= constantPoolSize; i++) {
                    byte tag = classFile.readByte();
                    switch (tag) {
                        case CONSTANT_Utf8:
                            String s = classFile.readUTF();
                            if (!s.startsWith("java") &&
                                !s.startsWith("com/sun/") &&
                                !s.startsWith("jdk/") &&
                                !s.startsWith("org/w3c/") &&
                                !s.startsWith("org/xml/") &&
                                !s.startsWith("org/ietf/jgss") &&
                                lastComponentIsUpperCase(s) &&
                                classNameMatcher.reset(s).matches() &&
                                !classes.contains(s)) {

                                // Found reference to a class name
                                // that isn't in this jar.
                                return Optional.of(s);
                            }
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_Integer:
                            classFile.readInt();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_Float:
                            classFile.readFloat();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_Long:
                            classFile.readLong();
                            i++;
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_Double:
                            classFile.readDouble();
                            i++;
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_Class:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_String:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_Fieldref:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_Methodref:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_NameAndType:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_MethodHandle:
                            classFile.readByte();
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_MethodType:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_Dynamic:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_Module:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        case CONSTANT_Package:
                            classFile.readShort();
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new IOException(
                                "Unknown constant pool tag " + tag);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Optional.empty();
}
```

This is far from perfect;  strings like "N/A" and "DES/ECB/NoPadding" look like class names.  It could be refined by assuming package names are entirely lowercase, but… I’m pretty sure not every project adheres to that practice.